# Unity console doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console, stack-trace

Usually, when I would print something using Debug.Log() it would show up in the console and I could double click on it to go to the function call. Also, a single click would expand the text to expose a kind of history of the calls (a certain function calls another function which called another one, and so on. Until the Debug.Log() was called).

But now I only get this weird behavior where the functions calls are replaced by the memory addresses of the stack.

I can't post images yet so here's [what the console looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YORax.jpg)

I can still manage to find where the call occurred by expanding the message but it's a nightmare

Can you find the call?
Hint: it's from PointCloudGenerator.cs at line 290

it wouldn't be so bad but the thing is that the double click behavior doesn't work at all and it's quite frustrating to try and figure out where the call originated. The exact same thing happens with warnings and errors too.

EDIT: I'm using Unity 5.6.3p3 and my editor is Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

This is where the log was called:

```
private IEnumerator ReadCornerData(long capacity, CloudBounds cloudBounds)
{
    List<Vector3> corners = new List<Vector3>();
    List<Vector3> borders = new List<Vector3>();

    using (MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\CornerData", capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            byte dataAvailable = 0;
            accessor.Write(0, ref dataAvailable);
            accessor.Write((int)capacity / 2, ref dataAvailable);

            int memIndex = 0;
            while (dataAvailable != 0xF)
            {
                accessor.Read(memIndex, out dataAvailable);
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(dataAvailable);
        }
    }
}
```

`
It's in a coroutine but it does the same thing when it is anywhere in my code really

Comment: You need to post the code/ function the log is showing you. Also, you need to mention your IDE and Unity version. Edit these into your question

Comment: @Programmer I just did, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the Console window tab/title box and set the Stack Trace Logging to Script Only instead of Full.

In most cases, this should also fix the "double click to open"  issue.

Comment: *"This shouldn't have any effect on the "double click to open" functionality though."* What's the point of this answer then? The problem is about not being able to double click on the error to open it.....

Comment: @Programmer The problem is about 2 things: weird formatting of log messages and the double click functionality. My answer addresses one of them. Are you saying it would be better for me to have not posted so OP gets neither problem answered instead of 1/2?

Comment: I  am not saying it is a bad thing. The **main** question OP talked about and want a fix for is the double click behavior but that's not addressed in your answer. EDIT: Sorry for that. Your answer should actually fix both issues.

Answer (score 0):

but after 12 years experience with unity, ive had the same problem.

Anwser to the double clicking not working-:

I'm currently using unity 2022.2.19f1, so might apply to you.

you may need to update the the Visual Studio Editor (and or) Visual studio code editor in the package manager in unity.

1. Click "Window" tab at the top of unity (in the taskbar)
2. Click "Package Manager" from the list
3. Make sure in the top left of package manager window, that the packages selected are "In Project" from the dropdown.
   4.scroll right to the bottom of the package list and click each of the packages mentioned above and the click update at bottom right of package window.

hopefully that should solve your problem